Understanding the Equivalence Conditions between Variance of Estimators in Linear Regression Models
Let $Y=\beta X+\epsilon$ be standard linear model, $\hat{\beta}$ and $\tilde{\beta}$ estimators of $\beta$ and $a\in R^{p}$.
We know that:
$$
Var(a'\tilde{\beta}) \le Var(a'\hat{\beta}).
$$
Is the following correct?
$$
Var(a'\tilde{\beta}) \le Var(a'\hat{\beta}) \Leftrightarrow a'Var(\tilde{\beta})a \le a'Var(\hat{\beta})a \Leftrightarrow Var(\tilde{\beta}) \le Var(\hat{\beta}).
$$

Yes, that is the definition of the matrix inequality in the last line. Note, the comparison of variance matrices only makes sense if both estimator are unbiased.
